# How do I keep a NUT2 UPS server connection alive in Python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

Background: I am using a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with an OpenUPS from Mini-Box to display LiPo battery information (Charge status/remaining battery percentage) using a SSD1306 128x64 OLED I2C display. The monitoring of the OpenUPS is done with NUT2 (Network UPS Tools) Python module.

The OpenUPS is connected via USB and I am using a custom Python module using a class to pull certain variables (ups status, battery percentage, voltage, etc.) using the NUT2 module (converted to Python3). The problem is, at some point the connection to the NUT server pipe closes and throws an [Errno32] broken pipe error upon attempt to get variables. I must keep the pipe alive while the Pi is on and operational and polling data as future code will require a low battery warning flashing on the display and constant battery monitoring with UPS-specific battery issues/errors.

I would like to know how I can accomplish this task of keeping the connection to the NUT server alive between periodic checks. Attached below is the code snippets. Keep in mind, I am not a professional programmer or even pretend to be good. If you see other aspects I can clean up or do more efficiently, I welcome it.

This is the UPS class module to setup NUT client and declare get functions:

```
from nut2 import PyNUTClient
import json

class UPS:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = PyNUTClient()
        self.ups = 'openups'
        
    def get_ups_status(self):
        self.ups_status = self.client.get(self.ups, 'ups.status')
        return (self.ups_status)

    def get_batt_chrg(self):
        self.batt_chrg = self.client.get(self.ups, 'battery.charge')
        return (self.batt_chrg)

    def get_batt_v(self):
        self.batt_v = self.client.get(self.ups, 'battery.voltage')
        return (self.batt_v)
```

This is the OLED display module I created:

```
from board import SCL, SDA
import busio
from oled_text import OledText, Layout64, BigLine, SmallLine
import time

class Oled:
    def __init__(self):
        i2c = busio.I2C(SCL, SDA)
        self.display = OledText(i2c, 128, 64)
            
    def displayBattLevel(self, ups_status, batt_chrg):
        self.batt_chrg = batt_chrg
        self.ups_status = ups_status
        self.display.layout = Layout64.layout_DefaultBatt()
        
        i_100 = '\uf240'
        i_75 = '\uf241'
        i_50 = '\uf242'
        i_25 = '\uf243'
        i_0 = '\uf244'
        i_chrg = '\uf376'
        i_lb = '\uf377'
        
        if self.ups_status == 'OL':
            self.display.layout = Layout64.layout_FullBatt()
            self.batt_chrg = 'BATTERY FULL'
            batt_icon = i_100
        elif self.ups_status == 'OL CHRG':
            batt_icon = i_chrg
        elif self.ups_status == 'LB':
            self.display.layout = Layout64.layout_LowBatt()
            batt_icon = i_lb
            self.batt_chrg = 'LOW BATTERY'
        else:
            if 76 <= self.batt_chrg:
                batt_icon = i_100
            elif 51 <= self.batt_chrg <= 75:
                batt_icon = i_75
            elif 26 <= self.batt_chrg <= 50:
                batt_icon = i_50
            elif 10 <= self.batt_chrg <= 25:
                batt_icon = i_25
            else:
                batt_icon = i_0
                
        x = isinstance(self.batt_chrg, int)
        
                
        if x == True:
            self.display.text(str(self.batt_chrg) + '%', 1)
        else:        
            self.display.text(self.batt_chrg, 1)
        
        self.display.text(batt_icon, 2)
    
    def clear(self):
        self.display.clear()
```

This is the main Python code that runs at boot using systemd. Notice I have the trigger for displaying information tied to a button on BCM GPIO pin 21.

```
from display import Oled
from UpsClient import UPS
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

oled = Oled()
ups = UPS()
batt_btn = 21

def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setup(batt_btn, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
    
def display(ev=None):
    ups_status = ups.get_ups_status()
    batt_chrg = int(ups.get_batt_chrg())

    oled.displayBattLevel(ups_status, batt_chrg)

    time.sleep(3)

    oled.clear()

def detect_loop():
     GPIO.add_event_detect(batt_btn, GPIO.FALLING, callback=display, bouncetime=200)
     while True:
        time.sleep(1)

setup()
detect_loop()
```